# Why does my CSS stylesheet not reflect when I pass conditional radio buttons through jQuery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been struggling with this for weeks now and I don't know how to get past it.

I have a pretty nice CSS style sheet to use with a form. The form has a conditional yes/no radio box that I finally got to work using javascript BUT the CSS styling is completely eliminated. Can someone please help me. I'm beyond confused at this point.

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #D2D6DB }

  
form
{
  display: block;
  margin: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 0;
}




@media(min-width:800px){
  form > div {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  form > div.col-submit {
    display: block;
  }
}



form > div > label
{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-family: Source Sans Pro, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #7f7f7f;
  cursor: pointer;
}

form > div > info
{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-family: Source Sans Pro, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*form > div > checkLabel
{
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  /*font-family: Source Sans Pro, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent:-15px;
}

form > div > checkLabel> input
{
  width:13px;
  height: 13 px;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  vertical align: bottom;
  position:relative;
  top:-1px;
  *overflow:hidden;
}
*/


form > div.col-2, form > div.col-3, form > div.col-4, 
form > div.col-5, form > div.col-6, form >div.col-7,
form > div.col-8,form > div.col-1, form > div.col-11{ 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
}

@media(min-width: 800px){
  form > div.col-2, form > div.col-3, form > div.col-4, 
  form > div.col-5,form > div.col-6, form >div.col-7, form > div.col-8,
  form > div.col-1, form > div.col-11
  { box-shadow: 1px 1px #E4E4E4; border: none; }  
}

@media(min-width:800px){
  form > div.col-2 { width: 50% }
  form > div.col-3 { width: 33.3333333333% }
  form > div.col-4 { width: 25% }
  form > div.col-1 {width: 100%}
  form > div.col-5 {width: 20%}
  form > div.col-6 {width: 16.6666666666%}
  form > div.col-7 {width:30%}
  form > div.col-8 {width:10%}
  form > div.col-11 {width:100%}
}

form > div > label > input
{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 27px;
  line-height: 27px;
  margin: 5px -5px 0;
  padding: 7px 5px 3px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
  opacity: .66;
  transition: opacity .3s, box-shadow .3s;
}

form > div.col-submit {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

form > div.col-1 {
  border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
  background: #051938 ;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 1px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media(min-width: 800px){
  form > div.col-submit button {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}


form > div.col-submit button:hover {
  background: #7f7f7f;
}

form > div > label > select
{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 16px 0 8px;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
  opacity: .33;
}

form > div > label > input:focus, form > div > label > select:focus
{
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}



/*input[type ="date"]{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 16px 0 -3px;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
  opacity: .33;

  height: 27px;
  line-height: 27px;
}*/

/*input[type ="date"]{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px -5px 0;
  padding: 7px 5px 2px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
  opacity: .33;
}

input[type "radio"]{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px -5px 0;
  padding: 7px 5px 3px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
  opacity: .33;
}*/

.sub-questions {
 margin: 0 0 1.5em 1em;
 padding: 0 0 0 1em;
 border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

li 
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

form > div > label > input[type="date"]
{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 13px 0 3px;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
  opacity: .33;
}

form > div > label > input[type="radio"]
{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 16px 0 8px;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
  opacity: .33;
}

 fieldset,
 legend {
    border:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

/*button {
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: none;

  text-transform: uppercase;
}*/

.control:checked ~ .conditional,
   #yes:checked ~ .conditional,
   #required-2:checked ~ .conditional
   #option-2:checked ~ .conditional {
    clip: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: static;
    width: auto;
   }

   .control:not(:checked) ~ .conditional,
   #yes:not(:checked) ~ .conditional,
   #required-2:not(:checked) ~ .conditional,
   #option-2:not(:checked) ~ .conditional {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
   }
```

```html
<?php
include("home.php");
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Personal Health Questionnaire</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Personal Health Questionnaire">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>
       <center>Employee Eligibility Statement</center>
      </h1>
    </header>

    <main>
  

        <form action="home.php" method = "POST">
     


  <!--Question 1-->
         <div class="col-1">
                <label>
                 
                </label>
            </div>    
          <div class ="col-11">
            <label><b>1. </b></label>
                 <info>Answer this thing
            <p></p>
           
          <li> <input  type ="radio" name = "yesno" value ="Yes" tabindex = "8" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" id="yesCheck"/> Yes
             <input type ="radio" name = "yesno" value ="No" tabindex = "8" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" id ="noCheck"/> No    
                   <b> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;   yes or no </b></li>
              <div id="ifYes" style="display:none">
                
<!-- conditional -->
         
          <div class ="col-4"> 
          <label>Person with the condition: <input type ="text" placeholder="First and last name"/></label>
        </div>
        
        <div class ="col-4">
          <label>Exact diagnosis: <input type ="text" placeholder = "Diagnosis"/></label>
        </div>
        
        
         <div class ="col-4"> 
          <label>Date diagnosed: <input type ="date" /></label>
        </div>
        
        <div class ="col-4">
          <label>Date last treated: <input type ="date" /></label>
        </div>
     
        <div class ="col-11">
          <info><b>List all medication(s) prescribed for this condition:</b></info>
        </div>
        
        <div class = "col-4">
          <label><center>Name:</center>
          <input type = "text" placeholder="First medication"/>
          <input type = "text" placeholder="Second medication"/>
          <input type = "text" placeholder="Third medication"/>
           </label>
          </div>
        
        
        <div class = "col-4">
          <label><center>Dosage:</center>
          <input type = "text" placeholder="Dosage for first medication"/>
          <input type = "text" placeholder="Dosage for second medication"/>
          <input type = "text" placeholder="Dosage for third medication"/>
           </label>
          </div>
          
          <div class = "col-4">
          <label><center>Frequency:</center>
          <input type = "text" placeholder="Frequency of first medication"/>
          <input type = "text" placeholder="Frequency of second medication"/>
          <input type = "text" placeholder="Frequency of third medication"/>
           </label>
          </div>
          
          <div class = "col-4">
          <label><center>Currently taking?</center>
            <select name ="CT1" tabindex ="">
              <option value = "Yes">Yes</option>
              <option value = "No">No</option>
            </select>
            
            <select name ="CT2" tabindex ="">
             <option value = "Yes">Yes</option>
              <option value = "No">No</option>
            </select>
            
            <select name ="CT3" tabindex ="">
             <option value = "Yes">Yes</option>
              <option value = "No">No</option>
            </select>
            
           </label>
          </div>
    
    </div>
        </info>  
          </div>
          
  <!-- End CONDITIONAL -->  

   <!-- how i want it to look-->
         
          <div class ="col-4"> 
          <label>Person with the condition: <input type ="text" placeholder="First and last name"/></label>
        </div>
        
        <div class ="col-4">
          <label>Exact diagnosis: <input type ="text" placeholder = "Diagnosis"/></label>
        </div>
        
        
         <div class ="col-4"> 
          <label>Date diagnosed: <input type ="date" /></label>
        </div>
        
        <div class ="col-4">
          <label>Date last treated: <input type ="date" /></label>
        </div>
     
        <div class ="col-11">
          <info><b>List all medication(s) prescribed for this condition:</b></info>
        </div>
        
        <div class = "col-4">
          <label><center>Name:</center>
          <input type = "text" placeholder="First medication"/>
          <input type = "text" placeholder="Second medication"/>
          <input type = "text" placeholder="Third medication"/>
           </label>
          </div>
        
        
        <div class = "col-4">
          <label><center>Dosage:</center>
          <input type = "text" placeholder="Dosage for first medication"/>
          <input type = "text" placeholder="Dosage for second medication"/>
          <input type = "text" placeholder="Dosage for third medication"/>
           </label>
          </div>
          
          <div class = "col-4">
          <label><center>Frequency:</center>
          <input type = "text" placeholder="Frequency of first medication"/>
          <input type = "text" placeholder="Frequency of second medication"/>
          <input type = "text" placeholder="Frequency of third medication"/>
           </label>
          </div>
          
          <div class = "col-4">
          <label><center>Currently taking?</center>
            <select name ="CT1" tabindex ="">
              <option value = "Yes">Yes</option>
              <option value = "No">No</option>
            </select>
            
            <select name ="CT2" tabindex ="">
             <option value = "Yes">Yes</option>
              <option value = "No">No</option>
            </select>
            
            <select name ="CT3" tabindex ="">
             <option value = "Yes">Yes</option>
              <option value = "No">No</option>
            </select>
            
           </label>
          </div>

 <!--  END how i want it to look-->
    <div class = "col-submit">
    <button type= "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit">Submit</button>
    </div>

  </form>
 </main>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';

  cssLink.href="style.css";
  cssLink.rel="stylesheet";
  cssLink.type="text/css";
}
</script>

    <!-- Your web-app is https, so your scripts need to be too -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-gvQgAFzTH6trSrAWoH1iPo9Xc96QxSZ3feW6kem+O00="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/custom.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqdonxbp/2/)

Comment: Please share your JS/CSS code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oqdonxbp/      I've included comments in the html document about how I want it to look and how it looks at the moment.You can see how I want it to look with the styling on the page - however, when you press the yes radio button, all the styling is stripped.

Comment: Have you seen the javascript error in console? 
Uncaught ReferenceError: cssLink is not defined.

Comment: ah sorry - i was trying various things out. that should not be there, let me remove it. https://jsfiddle.net/oqdonxbp/2/      Either way, it still does not work.

Comment: Your code should exist in the SO post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fiddle is updated, before you click on the link, two things:
1. Your HTML was duplicated hence the "style break"
2. You use a lot the symbol > in your CSS I suggest to NOT use excesively, the > means "direct children of" example:

```
<form>
   <div> <!-- The symbol > in css will affect this div only-->
       <div> <!-- Here the symbol > is not taking effect as this is not direct children of form-->
   </dv>
```

And finally the link to the  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqdonxbp/5/)

Hope this is helpful...

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been struggling so long with this. Thank you for the information about > as well. What did you you mean by 1?

Comment: Any time pal! Its a pleasure to helpyou, what I mean in 1  is that your form was duplicated, check your original fiddle the <div id="ifYes">had the form </div>and outside the div if yes you had the questions again.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selectors are different for both forms. Check the path from the `<form>` to the `<label>` for each. It's different.

For example, on the form that works the css selector is

`form > div > label`

But the path from the Yes form is:

`form > info > div > div > label`

Need to extend your CSS rules to account for that path.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I expanded on the answer.

Comment: I just removed some irrelevant pieces of css in this. https://jsfiddle.net/oqdonxbp/3/      But I'm not sure where you're getting the second path from? How do I go about fixing this without completely changing my css document.

Comment: Basically the HTML is different when your Yes radio button is checked than when your No radio button is checked. The CSS you have only works when No is checked. You need to look at the CSS rules you have, which only work for when No is checked, and then extend on them to support the HTML of when Yes is checked. The alternative is to re-write your HTML to be the same no matter which radio button is checked (this is preferred).